What type of 4.2 mm pitch connector is this?
Looking for this connector if anyone can help. Looks like Molex but different from the PCI express one which always show up on searches. 4.2 mm spacing up and down.


Any other dimensions? Any symbols or text on it?

Different in what way? This looks very much like a standard Molex part. Likely, that family of connectors has different keying as an option.

Looks similar to this, with different housing material (plain nylon) and potentially different keying: 8 pin connector identification

Molex make thousands of connectors, this one looks like one of their standard 6 pin Mini-Fit Jr (rather than the one used for PCI which is a custom design for that application).
5557 series, part number 39039062:

Full spec here on the Molex Web Site from where this picture is taken.
They do several alternatives in different colours and they're probably available from other manufacturers as well.
